# how to search by letter in column in database (laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to find by letter customer's first_name on my 'customers' table.

> And the only thing that I get is an empty array.
>
> > For instance, I put in the parameter 'q' value 'E' to get customer Elena from my database by I get an only empty array.

I use the following code to get first_name :
        $search = Input::get('q');

```
    if($search)
    {
        $customers = Customer::all()->where('full_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
        return ($customers);
    }
```

> Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$customers = Customer::where('full_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->get();
```

[Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Comment: It worked!
thank you !!
but may I know why my option did not work?

Comment: @Marius glad it helps. can you marked it as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Your query don't work because you are calling the `all()` method before the `where()`. That's actually not wrong, but it have different behavior.

When you call `all()`, it actually does the SQL query. After that, any chained methods are being called into a `Eloquent Collection` class, and it also have a where method, but that's simpler since it runs on PHO instead of running on SQL.

Since the collection's `where()` method doesn't support LIKE operator, it's probably searching for a value that is exactly `%E%`.

Hope it can help you understanding why your query doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Very helpful explanation.